# Making ArrayList on each index of List

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a List like this

```
public List<String>[] Depth_List;
```

Now at each index of this list i want to create and ArrayList. The Size of the Array will be given by user. The Function to intialize it is given as

```
public  void CreateList(int deep){
    Depth_List= new ArrayList<String>[deep];

        for (int d_i = 0; d_i <deep; d_i++)
        {
            Depth_List[d_i]= new ArrayList<String>();
        }

    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Regards

Comment: You cannot create an array of generic.

Comment: What do you want to do? An array of lists? Or just a 1D list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it like that:

```
public List<List<String>> depthList;
public  void CreateList(int deep) {
    depthList= new ArrayList<List<String>>();

    for (int d_i = 0; d_i <deep; d_i++) {
        depthList.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    }

}
```

Side note: please read about [Java naming conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm). Your code will be much more readable.

Comment: Additionally to the naming conventions I would like to mention the coding conventions for putting the { on the same line as the end of the for look construction: for (int d_i = 0; d_i <deep; d_i++) {

Comment: @Barnesy the [Egyptian braces](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html) ;)

Answer (score 2):

You cant set the size of your arrayList like in arrays (by using [])

Answer (score 2):

You can set the ArrayList for optimization purposes with an initial capacity:

```
public List<List<String>> createDepthList(int depth) 
{
  List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<List<String>>(depth);
  for int(i = 0; i < depth; i++) 
  {
    result.add(new ArrayList<String>());
  }
  return result;
}
```